# ClampingScrollPhysics when setted NeverScrollableScrollPhysics

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made PageView, set physics to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to disabled scroll and implements it by buttons. But when I call `controller.animateToPage(/* ... */)`, my PageView animated with scroll glow. How to disabled this behaviour? Or this is bug of Flutter itself?

Comment: What do  you want to disable? The scroll glow or you don't want your PageView to respond to scroll gesture?

Comment: @Omotayo4i i want disable both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable Scroll glow, create a class that extends `ScrollBehavior`

```
class DisableScrollGlowBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Then wrap your scrollable List widget with `ScrollConfiguration` widget using the behavior of the class created.

```
ScrollConfiguration(
   behavior: DisableScrollGlowBehavior(),
   child: ListView(
            children: [],
   ),
)
```